# Edit an Abaqus input file and Run it from Matlab

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulation, abaqus, calibration

I need perform 50 Abaqus simulations, each simulation analyses a certain material property and each differs by changing one parameter. So the idea is to write a Matlab script that:

1. opens the .inp file
2. edits the material parameter of interest
3. prints it into a new file which will be the new .inp file
4. runs it to perform the simulation

This is what I accomplished so far in a very simplified version:

```
f= fopen('PRD8_30s.inp'); 

c = textscan(f,'%s %s %s %s %s ','delimiter',','); 

fclose(f) ; 
S = [c{1}]; 
A = {'5e-08'} ;

S(12496) = A ; 

fid = fopen('file.inp','w') ;
fprintf(fid,'%s \n',S{:} );

fclose(fid) ;
```

[PRD_8_30s.inp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c0aSPAYJyDjVwHADIpktaJFa5AYJUwdf)

I manually found out the position of the parameter of interest (A at 12496 hence below the line **Viscoelastic*). The code actually changes the parameter I need but there are major problems: it prints a new file with additional lines with respect to the original .inp (12552 vs 8737) and it doesn't print the entire .inp but only the first column.

How can I edit the .inp changing the parameter and obtaining a new .inp with the edited parameter that can be used to run the new simulation?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is not multiple Gb in size, The following might help.

1. create a template input and mark the parameter you want to change as, for example `para_xxxx`
2. Use the following script:

```
    text=fileread('template.inp');
    newtext=replace(text,'para_xxxx',newParameter);
    fid=fopen('newcase.inp','w');
    fprintf(fid,newtext);
    fclose(fid);
```

The file name 'newcase.inp' should be updated each time in the loop.